# Extract list elements from a column of lists in Dask dataframe as individual rows

Tags: pandas, dask

I'm trying to use Dask to build a distance matrix which involves making a few million requests to an API. The API accepts one origin location and multiple destinations. To get the parameters for each individual request I'm building a Dask dataframe with the following code:

```
from dask import bag as db
origins = ['a','b','c','d','e']
dd = db.from_sequence(origins)
#all origin destination pairs (destinations are from the same set as origins)
dp = dd.product(dd)
# possible extra step to filter elements
# dp = dp.filter(lambda x: ...)
df = dp.to_dataframe()
df.columns = ['from','to']

# helper function to get chunks
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

chunk_size = 3 
destinationsd = df.groupby('from').apply(lambda x:[el.tolist() for el in list(chunks(x['to'], chunk_size))],meta=(0, list))
```

This gets me the following Series:

```
destinations = destinationsd.compute()
print(destinations)
>
from
b    [[a, b, c], [d, e]]
a    [[a, b, c], [d, e]]
e    [[a, b, c], [d, e]]
d    [[a, b, d], [c, e]]
c    [[b, c, a], [e, d]]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

The series contains all the request parameters for a single origin in one row. Instead of having all destinations for an origin in a single list I'd like to have individual rows for each origin-destinations list. I can do this in pandas:

```
final = res.apply(lambda x:pd.Series(x)).stack()
final.index = final.index.droplevel(1)
print(final)
>    
from
b    [a, b, c]
b       [d, e]
a    [a, b, c]
a       [d, e]
e    [a, b, c]
e       [d, e]
d    [a, b, d]
d       [c, e]
c    [b, c, a]
c       [e, d]
dtype: object
```

How can I get a similar result to `final` using Dask?